# Diagonal matrices are not necessarily square?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, svd

I have seen it implied, in the context of singular value decomposition, that diagonal matrices are not necessarily square. Is this true? How can it be true? Can someone please explain this in more detail?

Comment: Usually diagonal implies square, but possibly it could just mean that the off diagonal elements are zero.

Comment: @copper.hat this was in the context of singular value decomposition. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singular value decomposition of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is $A = U \Sigma V^\top$ where $U$ is $m \times m$ orthogonal, $V$ is $n \times n$ orthogonal, and $\Sigma$ is $m \times n$ diagonal ($\Sigma_{ij} = 0$ if $i \ne j$).

This is the only context where I have encountered non-square diagonal matrices. Otherwise, typically when one says "diagonal matrix" one usually assumes it is square, as copper.hat mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Yes!!! That seems to be what they meant

Comment: As an additional (completely off-topic) comment, singular value decomposition is one of the loveliest, most useful results in elementary linear algebra (in my opinion).  More people should teach it as part of their undergraduate "intro to linear algebra" classes.